# Coldfusion 10 admin password reset not working

Tags: coldfusion, passwords, reset

When i reset CF admin password using passwordreset.bat , the reset happens and can see the change in password.properties file like below

password=
encrypted=false

when i restart CF service in windows, in password.properties i can see encrypted string,

But my changed password is not working when I try to log in to the coldfusion administrator.

I tried multiple times, but it did not work.

Please advise what is wrong. with my admin password reset.

One more issue when i set admin.security.disabled false in neo-security.xml, in coldfusion administrator when i submit any form(like enabling debugging settings), it throws error like "There was an error accessing this page, check logs for more details, click here to login"

I am using browser IE 11.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved when I add 127.0.0.1 to list of trusted sites.